# Unit test for PINVOKE memory management

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, garbage-collection, pinvoke

I have a C# application (.net core 3.1) which uses some unmanaged C++ code. The interop is implemented using PINVOKE.

My code does something like this (simplified):

```
double[] managedArray = new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };

// This is the first PINVOKE call
// The unmanaged object is expected to copy the array internally.
UnmanagedObject unmanaged = CreateUnmanagedObject(managedArray);

[...]

// This is another PINVOKE call which uses the data passed in to the constructor.
// This call can also happen in a different method.
// At this point managedArray could already have been garbage collected.
unmanaged.DoStuff();
```

I'm following the pattern, that the C++ code should copy the array internally before storing it in the UnmanagedObject state.

Now I'd like to write a unit test for the proposition *The unmanaged object is expected to copy the array internally.*
My attempt looks like this:

```
UnmanagedObject unmanaged;
{
    double[] managedArray = new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
    unmanaged = CreateUnmanagedObject(managedArray);
}
// With this call I'm relying on the fact, that the GC will collect
// managedArray, because it's gone out of scope.
System.GC.Collect();

// If DoStuff works properly here, it means that the C++ code
// has copied the array internally.
unmanaged.DoStuff();
```

Is the phrase *the GC will collect `managedArray`, because it's gone out of scope* correct? Is that guaranteed to always happen?

[I edited the question to make it more clear by removing some irrelevant stuff. Some of the comments do not apply anymore.]

Comment: You don't need to pin/fix array of primitive types before passing them to pinvoke. You can pass them directly and the .NET will pin them for you **for the duration of the method call** (so they'll be unpinned when the pinvoke returns)

Comment: did you read comment *And of course note that intPtr only points to the array while control is in the fixed block* ... also it depends what `CreateUnmanagedObject` does

Comment: The real code is more complicate than this, I need to do that. That doesn't have anything to do with the question anyway. The question is about how to write a test for the fact that the unmanaged code will still work after the method call.

Comment: @Selvin yes, that's why I wrote " I'm following the pattern, that the C++ code should copy the array internally". I want to avoid copying the array twice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pin/fix array of primitive types before passing them to pinvoke. You can pass them directly and the .NET will pin them for you for the duration of the method call (so they'll be unpinned when the pinvoke returns)

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll")]
private static extern UnmanagedObject CreateUnmanagedObject(double[] array, int lenArray);
```

If you want to check if your data is really copied by the C++ internally you can:

```
UnmanagedObject unmanaged;
{
    double[] managedArray = new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };

    unmanaged = CreateUnmanagedObject(managedArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < managedArray.Length; i++)
    {
        managedArray[i] = double.NaN;
    }
}

// At this point the GC should collect the managedArray, if I trigger it.
System.GC.Collect();

// If DoStuff works properly here, it means that the C++ code
// has copied the array internally
unmanaged.DoStuff();
```

So you can set the values of the array to other values.

You could even check if the object has really been collected:

```
WeakReference wr;

{
    double[] managedArray = new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
    wr = new WeakReference(managedArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < managedArray.Length; i++)
    {
        managedArray[i] = double.NaN;
    }
}

// At this point the GC should collect the managedArray, if I trigger it.
System.GC.Collect();

if (wr.IsAlive)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Warning: the object hasn't been collected");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The object has been collected");
}
```

Note that if the program has been compiled in Debug mode, the GC doesn't collect objects until the end of the method, while in Release mode the objects can be collected at the end of the scope.

Comment: About the passing the array directly: I can't do that (the c++ function expects a void* and it should work with any array of built-in types). That has nothing to do with the question anyway. Of course I can change the array manually. But I was asking if I can rely on the garbage collector, or if I have to do it myself.